# Django how to set the default language in the i18n_patterns?

Tags: python, django

**settings.py**

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'hi'
# list of activated languages
LANGUAGES = (
    ('hi', _('Hindi')),
    ('en', _('English')),
)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^', include('howdy.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('accounts.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls'))
)
```

**Middleware**

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
]
```

So the default I set here is `"hi"` , but whenever I am hitting the URL[private mode] without appending any language in it, its redirecting with "en" in the url, not the "hi". What I am missing here to make it default point to "hi" language ?

Comment: What is "URL[private mode]"?

Comment: @udi, I open the browser in "incognito" mode to ensure that the Site is open afresh.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using `LocaleMiddleware`? See: [How Django discovers language preference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference):

> **LocaleMiddleware** tries to determine the user’s language preference by
> following this algorithm:
>
> - First, it looks for the language prefix in the requested URL. This is
>   only performed when you are using the **i18n_patterns** function in your
>   root URLconf. [...]
> - Failing that, it looks for a cookie.
>   The name of the cookie used is set by the **LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME**
>   setting. (The default name is *django_language*.)
> - Failing that, it looks at the **Accept-Language** HTTP header. This header
>   is sent by your browser and tells the server which language(s) you
>   prefer, in order by priority. Django tries each language in the header
>   until it finds one with available translations.
> - Failing that, it uses the global **LANGUAGE_CODE** setting.

Comment: Yep I am using it, I have edited my answer, please have a look

Answer (score 1):

[Locale Middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference) fetches the language code for the response in the following order:

- URL Language Prefix (/en/,/hi/) when using i18n_patterns in the urlpatterns
- `django.conf.global_settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME` cookie in the request object
- Accept-Language HTTP header
- `LANGUAGE_CODE` setting

If the user hits / and language cookie isn't set on the browser, then `LocaleMiddleware` uses the first compatible language in the Accept-Language header. That is the source of bugs in this case.

The solutions that can work are

1. Remove the `LocaleMiddleware` if it doesn't affect your development.
2. Create a custom middleware that sits before the `LocaleMiddleware` and sets a key in the `request.COOKIES` dictionary. It's a bit hacky but it works. And you can set the language cookie when you're sending a response and it would be saved on the browser. To make sure you don't override user's settings you can check if session's keys to check if the language code (`django.utils.translation.LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY`) is there.