# How to set default language in multi language Django project

Tags: python, django, django-models

my settings :

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fa'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Tehran'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Languages

LANGUAGES = (
    ('fa', _('Persian')),
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('ar', _('Arabic')),
)

LOCALE_PATHS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'locale/',
]
```

i want at the beginning when server get start default language for everyone be "fa" but it's still "en"
how can i change that ?
everything about multi language and translation works well

Comment: May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42553488/django-how-to-set-the-default-language-in-the-i18n-patterns) can help you

Comment: @Rvector  unfortunately how you can see there is no good answer in that Question

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default language like this in your `settings.py`:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = "ja" # <- default language
```

Comment: i did that in above "fa", but still "en" is default

Comment: can you please help me !!! when i remove English from LANGUAGES, LANGUAGE_CODE works as way to set default app language... but when en exists in the list... English become default.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but thankfully found the solution [LINK](https://gist.github.com/vstoykov/1366794).

If you don't know how to create custom middlewares, this tutorial can help you [LINK](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/18/how-to-create-a-custom-django-middleware.html).